# Adding each column in a 2D array which become values of the last row

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to add all of the values for each column in a 2D array and these sums become values that overwrite the last row of the array

for example:

```
4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5
0 0 0 0 0 //this row will be replaced by the sum of each column

4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5
5 7 9 11 13

public static void fillTotals(int[][] scores)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < scores.length - 1; r++)
    {
        scores[r][0] += count;
        scores[scores.length - 1][scores[0].length - 1] = count;
    }
}
```

I thought I could keep the columns the same and add it down with the changing rows but it isn't rewriting the last row. Also I don't know how to change the values at the bottom

Comment: Can we assume that the last row of `scores` should be treated as empty?

Comment: Yes, in all of the preconditions written: they are all 0's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate once over all rows and columns, actually iterate over all rows, for every column.  If you assume that the number of columns is the same for every row, then you can use `scores[0].length` as a fixed value.

```
public static void fillTotals(int[][] scores) {
    for (int c=0; c < scores[0].length; ++c) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int r=0; r < scores.length - 1; ++r) {
            sum += scores[r][c];
        }
        scores[scores.length - 1][c] = sum;
    }
}
```

This assumes that the final row of the 2D array is not part of the sum and is available to be overwritten with the sum of all preceding values, for each column.

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you so much! I originally tried doing a nested for loop but it didn't work so I thought I had to just change the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason that nothing is being updated is that you never change `count`, so you just end up adding 0 to everything. I think what you want instead of:

```
scores[r][0] += count;
```

is:

```
count += scores[r][0];
```

That way count will contain the summation of every element in the first column.

To be clear, `scores[r][0] += count;` is the same as `scores[r][0] = scores[r][0] + count;`, whereas I think you probably want `count = scores[r][0] + count;`

That being said, Im still pretty sure this code isnt actually going to work (sorry), since you only ever actually sum values from the first column. However, for the sake of not just doing way may be a school assignment for you, Im just going to leave it there. If you're still stuck let me know, and I'll try to help!